Laravel Test not updating the new test files
I am using Laravel 11, installed Laravel Breeze and PHPUnit Test. I changed where to store my User model, something like app\Infra\Models\User.php
I run "php artisan test" to run all the basic Tests of Breeze. I got failed tests which used old User path with message "Class "App\User" not found". I updated the right User path and run "php artisan test" again but nothing changed. I still got failed tests with that message.
Does Laravel cache test files somewhere I didn't know or I missed something in configuration?

Run composer dump-autoload judt in case and let us know what happened

I did "composer dump-autoload" many times but still got that message. If I use User::create(), everything is good but User::factory()->create(). That error occurred. I have no idea I should rise an issue on Laravel Git.

@matiaslauriti I found the problem was that Models folder path was hard-code in function modelName() of Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\Factory.php (line 780). That means we can't change the folder path to store our models if using Factory to generate data. This maybe a note for Laravel beloved. Thanks for your reply anyway.

Always share the full error then, because we could have found it in there

I figured out the issue. People who changed the default Models folder path for any reason and wanted using Factory to generate data. You should show Laravel your custom-path of Model by override $model attribute of Factory model. Specifically, you add 'protected $model = ;' into you factory.
In my case, I created UserFactory and add 'protected $model = "app\Infra\Models\User"'. There you go. All tests passed!
